# Codeigniter email config file causes date() timezone error

Tags: php, codeigniter

Codeigniter 3.0.3
I had just created new email.php config file in application\config folder,

I tried to add just 1 parameter in config array, and then if i open my web application then i get below message,

Below is config parameters,

```
$config = array(

'mailtype'  => 'html'

);
```

A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Warning

Message: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1036
```

If i remove contents from array, then there is no message,
I am not sure what is causing this error by adding config array,

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This is because no timezone has set in php configuration.

Add the following line of code to top of your php.ini file

```
date.timezone = "US/Central"
```

And restart web server

**OR**

you can set it via php script also by using following function:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Comment: Will it overwrite from my customer set TZ per user? Which will be master?

Comment: Also reload apache for top option

Comment: it will but depends on your code. You can set it dynamically by using `date_default_timezone_set` for each user in your script

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to put the timezone in a configuration line in your php.ini file. You should have a block like this in your php.ini file:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = America/New_York
```

If not, add it (replacing the timezone by yours). After configuring, make sure to restart httpd (service httpd restart).

[Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) you can find all list of supported timezones.

Answer (score 0):

You can add in the index.php

```
if( ! ini_get('date.timezone') ){
   date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
}
```

The problem is that you don't have set the time zone yet

Answer (score -1):

You need to set timezone of the server. Next steps works for me.

You must open `system/libraries/Email.php` and find function **_set_date()**.
Put following code line at top of funcion.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); // <-- 'UTC' is a string to define timezone
```

Then, function shall have the following struture

```
protected function _set_date()
{
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $timezone = date('Z');
    ...
}
```